# why APEX collection attribute not updating in Dynamic action on change event?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am trying change the collection attribute in OnChange event below. But, collection is not updating with new value. Can anyone help me if am missing anything?

Item Name - P2_CHANGE_ENTRY
Created 3 dynamic actions as below -

```
1. SetValue
    JavaScript Expression => this.triggeringElement.value
    Affected Elements =>P2_CHANGE_ENTRY
2. Execute PL/SQL Code
    PL/SQL Code => null
    Items to Submit => P2_CHANGE_ENTRY
    Items to Return => null
3. Execute PL/SQL Code
    **PL/SQL Code =>**  

    begin

       apex_collection.update_member_attribute (
                        p_collection_name =>'NEW_COLLECTION',
                        p_seq =>1,
                        p_attr_number =>3,
                        p_attr_value =>:P2_CHANGE_ENTRY); 

    end;

    Items to Submit => P2_CHANGE_ENTRY
    Items to Return => null
```

And in the process am inserting above attribute value in to Database but its inserting value as 'null'. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: I just replicated your case and it works fine for me.  However, I only created dynamic action 3 from your example, I don't understand what the first 2 are for?

Comment: 1=> for taking onchange selected value using javascript from LOV and affected item is P2_CHANGE_ENTRY

2=> Submitting above value  in "Items to Submit" 

Are you able read the attribute value in process as below - 

SELECT c003  FROM APEX_collections  WHERE collection_name = 'NEW_COLLECTION'  and seq_id = 1

am getting c003 as null in my process.

Comment: Yes it works for me.  But you seem to be doing something different.  Is your LOV/select list not also an APEX item?  Otherwise I don't see why you'd need to copy its value to another item.  Maybe you can put a working example of the issue on apex.oracle.com?

Comment: Apex Item only - 
APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_LOV_XL(1,d.c001,'DEPT',p_attributes=>'readonly onchange="deptchanged()" style="width: 150px" class="dept"',p_null_text=>NULL,p_show_extra=>'YES',p_null_value=>NULL).

DEPT is LOV which is select r, d from table;

Comment: Too bad ... your question didn't stick. Well, my upvotes will, just a shame about that -155 that kicked in now ;-(

Answer (score 0):

```
apex_collection.update_member_attribute (
    p_collection_name => 'NEW_COLLECTION',
    p_seq => '1',
    p_attr_number => '3',
    p_attr_value => :P2_CHANGE_ENTRY
);
```

Remember to use single quotes

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?